# How can I auto-add my posts to my site's Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook

My readers are telling me to manually add my posts to my fan page, but I'm trying to reduce steps and keep from forgetting.

Anyone know how I can automate this?

Comment: I went through some trouble doing exactly this and I eventually found a very simple solution. I use a Facebook app called RSS Graffiti ( http://www.rssgraffiti.com/ ). It doesn't get any easier, doesn't consume your server resources, and works perfectly.

Comment: This plugin seen to work the best for me.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-fb-comments/

Comment: A few days ago Wordpress released a plugin that does this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to automate the publishing of your WordPress posts to your Facebook fan page is to use Facebook's built in Notes application.

You will need your sites feed link which is usually http://example.com/feed.

Go to your fan page and click the edit page link then go to applications and under "Notes" click "go to app" at the bottom left hand side of the page you will see a link for "edit import settings" click the link and enter your feed url.

Everytime you publish a post a new note will be created that contains the post.  It will also publish an excerpt to your wall with a thumbnail image of the first image in the post.

Comment: I've been doing that, but people complain because when they click the post they're forced to read it in the Notes app, which strips mutlimedia, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to look into something like [`stream.publish`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) on facebook's api documention reference.

> This method publishes a post into the
>   stream — on the Wall of the current or
>   specified user, or on the Wall of a
>   friend or a Facebook Page, group, or
>   event connected to the current session
>   or specified user (but not to an
>   application profile page). By default,
>   this call publishes to the current
>   session user's Wall, but if you
>   specify a user ID, Facebook Page ID,
>   group ID, or event ID as the
>   target_id, then the post appears on
>   the Wall of the target, and not the
>   user posting the item.

As for using it, I've not explored much in the way of Facebook's API beyond `<fb:like>` tags.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** You try this [link/plugin](http://www.cravingtech.com/how-to-submit-blog-posts-from-wordpress-to-facebook-automatically.html) for WordPress. There is a plugin ("[WordBooker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordbooker/)") that looks promising.

Comment: That sounds right. But I don't know how to use that. I wonder if there's a plugin that would do it for me or some other pre-made solution.

Comment: See my edits the answer. There's a plugin called "WordBooker" which does what I think you want to do. I couldn't quite figure it out because there are a LOT of settings.

Answer (score 0):

- using [Facebook official plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/)
- you first create an app the get the (app id) and (app secret) for that app
- configure app settings to point to your domain name and url
- you will find more menu links under Facebook
- all the description is here in these two videos

  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc07rOKlzok
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMVOzoAEO9k&feature=c4-overview&list=UUSP6R8uFvIaOOwwxbZEjh5Q
- the plugin provides auto publish features for any post or custom post